# Additional logger - log4j / slf4j / Spring / WildFly

Tags: java, spring, log4j, wildfly, slf4j

I'm trying to add an additional logger into a Spring application which running on WildFly 14.0.1 server. Application already uses **slf4j+log4j** for logging. I tried to add an extra **appender** into the **log4j.xml** and **periodic-rotating-file-handler** into the **standalone.xml** but with no success. It looks like they are overwritten by some other file.

Here is log4j.xml:

<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/">

```
<!-- Console Appender -->
<appender name="STDOUT" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{HH:mm:ss,SSS} [%-5p] (%F:%L) - %m%n"/>
    </layout>
</appender>

<!-- DailyRollingFile Appender -->
<appender name="DRFILE" class="org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender">
    <param name="Threshold" value="debug"/>
    <param name="File" value="./log/terminal.log"/>
    <param name="Append" value="true"/>
    <param name="DatePattern" value="'.'yyy-MM-dd"/>
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss,SSS} [%-5p] (%F:%L) - %m%n"/>
    </layout>
</appender>

<appender name="DRCSVFILE" class="org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender">
    <param name="Threshold" value="debug"/>
    <param name="File" value="./log/requests.log"/>
    <param name="Append" value="true"/>
    <param name="DatePattern" value="'.'yyy-MM-dd"/>
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss,SSS} [%-5p] (%F:%L) - %m%n"/>
    </layout>
</appender>

<logger name="com.terminal.spring.logging" >
    <level value="INFO"/>
    <appender-ref ref="DRCSVFILE" />
</logger>

<root>
    <priority value="INFO"/>
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT"/>
    <appender-ref ref="DRFILE"/>
</root>
```

</log4j:configuration>

WildFly's standalone.xml snippet:

```
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:logging:6.0">
        <console-handler name="CONSOLE">
            <level name="DEBUG"/>
            <formatter>
                <named-formatter name="CONSOLE-PATTERN"/>
            </formatter>
        </console-handler>
        <periodic-rotating-file-handler name="FILE" autoflush="true">
            <level name="DEBUG"/>
            <formatter>
                <named-formatter name="PATTERN"/>
            </formatter>
            <file relative-to="jboss.server.log.dir" path="terminal.log"/>
            <suffix value=".yyyy-MM-dd"/>
            <append value="true"/>
        </periodic-rotating-file-handler>
        <periodic-rotating-file-handler name="CSVFILE" autoflush="true">
            <level name="DEBUG"/>
            <formatter>
                <named-formatter name="PATTERN"/>
            </formatter>
            <file relative-to="jboss.server.log.dir" path="requests.log"/>
            <suffix value=".yyyy-MM-dd"/>
            <append value="true"/>
        </periodic-rotating-file-handler>
        <logger category="com.arjuna">
            <level name="WARN"/>
        </logger>
        <logger category="org.jboss.as.config">
            <level name="INFO"/>
        </logger>
        <logger category="com.terminal">
            <level name="${env.DEBUG_LEVEL:INFO}"/>
        </logger>
        <logger category="sun.rmi">
            <level name="WARN"/>
        </logger>
        <root-logger>
            <level name="INFO"/>
            <handlers>
                <handler name="CONSOLE"/>
                <handler name="FILE"/>
            </handlers>
        </root-logger>
        <formatter name="PATTERN">
            <pattern-formatter pattern="%d{dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss,SSS} [%-5p] (%F:%L) - %m%n"/>
        </formatter>
        <formatter name="CONSOLE-PATTERN">
            <pattern-formatter pattern="%K{level}%d{HH:mm:ss,SSS} [%-5p] (%F:%L) - %m%n"/>
        </formatter>
    </subsystem>
```

However, terminal.log is successfully created, but requests.log isn't.

Does somebody know anything about it?

Answer (score 0):

This additional logger definition was missing in the standalone.xml file:

```
<logger category="com.terminal.spring.logging">
     <level name="DEBUG"/>
     <handlers>
          <handler name="CSVFILE"/>
     </handlers>
</logger>
```